# What happens when you die?

Tags: diablo-iii

Diablo's first and second installments handled death differently, both in terms of exp\gold penalties and also in if you respawned or not or instead had to reload from an earlier point.

In Diablo III what happens when you die?

Comment: I believe you just incur a 10% durability loss and probably have to run back, like in WoW.

Comment: Depends on your religious beliefs (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of patch 2.0.1, you are now given 3 options when you die (after a 3 second timer):

1. Respawn at your corpse

   - Has a countdown of 5 seconds
   - Limited to a total of 3 times within a short period of time
   - Cannot be used during boss fights.
   - Seems to replenish a 'charge' once every 1-2 minutes.
2. Respawn at the last checkpoint

   - Instant
   - No limit to number of times
3. Respawn in town

   - Instant
   - No limit to number of times

Comment: @Bora http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/dealing-with-answers-extending-existing-answers  I have no issues though if Oak wants to link to this answer or update his answer.

Answer (score 45):

This answer is outdated as of patch 2.0.1 - please see [z's answer instead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158081/122).

---

When you die, you need to wait a few seconds and then your character respawns in the last check-point or at the beginning of the current dungeon floor. You respawn with full health, full resources (unless you're a barb), and in the same game state (so no monsters are resurrected).

If you died during a boss of mini-boss fight (purple name), however, you respawn in the checkpoint right before the boss and the fight is completely reset - the boss has full HP again.

If you are level 10 or above, **you lose 10% of the current durability of each of your items.**

Comment: so lets say the items go from 100 to 90 (10%). Can you repair your item to the full 100 or is the new max durability now 90? im not clear

Comment: @chance the max durability is unaffected. I've edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: *Poke*: Update your answer :P

Comment: @Ender it is indeed outdated, but since at the moment I don't have anything to add beyond z's answer, it would be better if you could accept his instead :)

Comment: @Oak, a noble sacrifice indeed ;) +1

Answer (score 6):

In Diablo III, dead players respawn at the last checkpoint they reached. The good thing is that you no longer have to hunt for your corpse, the character will be wearing all the equipment and will have full health.

I don't believe there is any experience or gold loss upon death either, [but seems there is loss in durability](http://www.diablowiki.net/Death) of an item

Answer (score 5):

*Thankfully* I have yet to die, but I did find this explaining [death in Diablo 3](http://www.diablowiki.net/Death).

> Hardcore characters are as they were in Diablo II; mortal. One death
>   there is the end of a character. Forever.
>
> For non-hardcore characters in Diablo III, death is a very temporary
>   setback. Dead players can be resurrected by other players on the spot,
>   or after a few second delay they may choose to respawn at the last
>   checkpoint they reached. When they respawn they are wearing all of
>   their equipment and have full health; there is no corpse to retrieve
>   or loot as there was in Diablo 2. Characters do not lose any
>   experience or gold upon death...

As noted in their sit-down demo at E3, the developers did mention having to pay a *hefty* amount of gold in repairs after wiping.

Answer (score 2):

When you die, and in a group. Each party member can resurrect you by activating your grave/remains.

You can than select if to resurrect at that point, or resurrect at the last checkpoint (as stated before)
*you still loose 10% durability if you are higher than level 10.

Comment: You do realize the question has been answered for weeks right?

Comment: Yes, but no one mentioned the fact/option that you can be resurrected by other players.

Comment: @Ender It doesn't matter when an answer is posted if it adds new material previously unmentioned. The main thing to focus on is getting the best, most comprehensive answer possible not only for you, but also for people who visit this question in the future.

Comment: @Mana I know this, but his answer doesnt add anything the other answers havent already mentioned.