# What happens to the enemy's health after you die?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have seen [this post about death in D3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66244/what-happens-when-you-die) but it does not answer my question above.

If you are alone or in a party, pull some enemy or enemies, then do a bunch of damage, but do NOT kill them, what happens to their health **after you wipe?**  Does it get reset to full health again? or does something else happen?

Comment: I don't have evidence to back this up (at work), but their health stays the same in solo mode (confirmed, untested in co-op but assumed to be the same). I've died, respawned, and returned to the enemy/enemies who killed me and their health was exactly where it was at the time of my death. I can't say much about their health regenerating or anything along those lines, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For normal enemies, including champions and rare mobs, damaged health will not return (assuming they have no self-healing abilities in the first place). On higher difficulties, however, they *will* regen, slowly (though dead champs stay dead, thankfully!)

For bosses, dying means they will reset to phase 1 and must be beaten starting from the beginning again. (Cinema scenes will replay too).

Dying while in a party is similar. Unlike in regular combat, you will not be able to revive until the boss is dead, and while losing a party member in the middle of a boss fight might make it harder, the boss won't reset until *all* of the party has been slain.

Comment: Dying in multi-phase bossfights IS. *THE.* ***WORST.***

Comment: @IanPugsley Especially to lag. Suck it, Belial! I got you in the end!

Comment: @RavenDreamer - are you sure there is no health regen for elites/champions?  I've seen reports of them regening *while you are fighting them*. Though that could be because of vampiric or some other ability.

Comment: @EBongo Vampiric champions would definitely regen, but again, that's a specific affix. In the general case, they don't heal.

Comment: I can confirm Raven's answer.  I have noticed the same thing, as I was also curious about this.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: In higher difficulties at least, champions and rare mobs *will* regen health even without vampiric or similar abilities. I've sat at the "death" screen and watched them wander around with their health ticking up.

Comment: Actually you can res a person in the middle of the fight, I've ressed a friend on Diablo on Nightmare and been ressed on Izual on nightmare too. It can be quite hard to achieve though, but it is possible.

Comment: @Holger - The mechanic you describe is not what Raven was talking about. Being able to ressurect your party is implied.

Answer (score 1):

In later difficulties (definitely inferno, I don't recall hell), champs will regen life when no one is in combat with them.  They might even do it while in combat, but if so I haven't noticed that.
If you have to run across the map it's not uncommon to find mobs fully healed.  Kite them back to your spawn place to minimize such healing.

Comment: Confirmed for Hell Act 1 (solo at least) also, not sure about lower than that. I *think* a similar effect happens in Nightmare also, but not 100%.

Comment: Also, thanks for bringing this question back to my attention, I meant to dig it back up and add to Raven Dreamers answer.