# What determines whether or not an enemy heals for full health?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do enemies regenerate health?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68634/when-do-enemies-regenerate-health)

Sometimes, in Diablo 3, an enemy heals for full health. I can't really find a pattern to when they heal. I know it seems to occur after I die but I can't really figure it out beyond that. What determines whether or not an enemy heals? Does it differ depending on what difficulty your playing?

Answer (score 1):

It's time-based and dependent on difficulty. Lower difficulties get longer timers and I believe normal doesn't have one at all. I don't have exact numbers because I never timed it on lower difficulties but they heal to full much more quickly on Inferno (consistently ~8-10 seconds). I only have experience in single-player, so I can't speak to mechanics in multiplayer, but the timer only seems to start after they drop out of combat for whatever reason.